# Fail to connect to Rabbitmq using Spring 4.0 webstocket stomp api

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-4, spring-messaging, spring-websocket

I tried to make STOMP connection to RabbitMQ using Spring 4.0 WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer class, but failed ?

Snap of code is here.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        StompBrokerRelayRegistration StompBrokerRelayRegistration = config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/");
        StompBrokerRelayRegistration.setApplicationLogin("guest");
        StompBrokerRelayRegistration.setApplicationPasscode("guest");
        StompBrokerRelayRegistration.setAutoStartup(true);
        StompBrokerRelayRegistration.setRelayHost("localhost");
        StompBrokerRelayRegistration.setRelayPort(15674);
```

Note that

- I am using spring boot to run application. In fact I am changing the existing spring example "[gs-messaging-stomp-websocket](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket)". and changing class [WebSocketConfig](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket/blob/master/complete/src/main/java/hello/WebSocketConfig.java).
- Rabbitmq is locally installed with STOMP plugin enabled.
- Added all the maven dependency like spring-rabbitmq.

Do I need to do any thing else ?

Thanks,
Rafiq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got the issue

```
StompBrokerRelayRegistration StompBrokerRelayRegistration = config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/");
```

We need to pass the stomp supported "uri" instead of "/" vhost.

```
StompBrokerRelayRegistration StompBrokerRelayRegistration = config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue", "/amq/");
```

Comment: hello @Rafiq could you please post your full stomp config ?